# Java 7zip - "Not implemented" Error when trying to create zip file. Works for other formats

Tags: java, 7zip

The Java 7zip binding fails when creating a new ZIP file. Same code works for all other format and creates valid archives.

Maven dependency:

```
  <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
                <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding</artifactId>
                <version>16.02-2.01</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
                <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms</artifactId>
                <version>16.02-2.01</version>
            </dependency>
```

Code below fails when iterating through the ZIP ArchiveFormat.

```
        File tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("test").toFile();
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
            File f = new File(tempDir,"file"+i+".txt");
            f.createNewFile();
        }
        File[] files = tempDir.listFiles();
        
        
        for(ArchiveFormat format : ArchiveFormat.values()) {
            
            if(format.isOutArchiveSupported()) {
            
            LOGGER.info("trying format: {}",format);
            
            File file = new File(tempDir,"myzip."+format.name());
            
            LOGGER.info("trying file: {}",file);
            
            try {
                
                
                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
                
                IOutCreateArchive<IOutItemAllFormats> outArchive = SevenZip.openOutArchive(format);
                
                if (outArchive instanceof IOutFeatureSetLevel) {
                    ((IOutFeatureSetLevel) outArchive).setLevel(5);
                }
                
                if (outArchive instanceof IOutFeatureSetMultithreading) {
                    ((IOutFeatureSetMultithreading) outArchive).setThreadCount(2);
                }
                
                 outArchive.createArchive(new RandomAccessFileOutStream(raf),
                            files.length, new IOutCreateCallback<IOutItemAllFormats>() {
                                @Override
                                public void setTotal(long total) throws SevenZipException {}
                                @Override
                                public void setCompleted(long complete) throws SevenZipException {}
                                @Override
                                public void setOperationResult(boolean operationResultOk) throws SevenZipException {}
                                @Override
                                public IOutItemAllFormats getItemInformation(int index, OutItemFactory<IOutItemAllFormats> outItemFactory) throws SevenZipException {
                                    LOGGER.info("getItemInformation: {}",index);
                                    File file = files[index];
                                    IOutItemAllFormats item = outItemFactory.createOutItem();
                                    item.setDataSize(file.length());
                                    //item.setPropertyIsDir(false);
                                    item.setPropertyPath(file.getName());
                                    
                                    return item;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public ISequentialInStream getStream(int index) throws SevenZipException {
                                    try {
                                        return new InputStreamSequentialInStream(new FileInputStream(files[index]));
                                    } 
                                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                                    }
                                }
                     
                 });

                 outArchive.close();
                 LOGGER.info("created archive: {}",file);
            } catch (net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZipException | IllegalStateException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error creating format "+format,e);
                file.delete();
            }
            
         
            }
        }
```

Exception is on the createArchive call...

```
net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZipException: HRESULT: 0x80004001 (Not implemented). Error creating 'zip' archive with 1 items
at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.impl.OutArchiveImpl.nativeUpdateItems(Native Method)
at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.impl.OutArchiveImpl.doUpdateItems(OutArchiveImpl.java:141)
at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.impl.OutArchiveImpl.createArchive(OutArchiveImpl.java:150)
at TestingView.lambda$3(TestingView.java:339)
```

Not sure what other details to but SO is complaining about *too much code*...